# Convert number to date in PHP and format to YYYYMMDD

Tags: php, datetime

I want to convert date from, for example, 1441065600 to `YYYYMMDD` format. How do I do that?

```
$temp = date("Y-m-d",1441065600);
$rel_date = date_format( $temp, "YYYYMMDD");
```

The code above gives an error:

> `date_format()` expects parameter 1 to be `DateTimeInterface`

Comment: There is no need for the second line of code, just change the first one a bit and you already have what you need as `date()` formats a date: `$rel_date = date("Ymd",1441065600);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using date()

Simply write:

```
<?php

echo date('Ymd', 1441065600);
```

Otherwise, using a [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instance:

### Short

```
<?php

echo (new DateTime())->setTimestamp(1441065600)->format('Ymd');
```

Note: the `setTimestamp()` method do not takes a string as parameter! Otherwise, you may want to do so:

### Long

```
<?php

$english = '1441065600';
$timestamp = strtotime($english);
$date = new DateTime($timestamp);
echo $date->format('Ymd'); // 20161214
```

### Descriptions

> [strtotime()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
>
> [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) - Representation of date and time

Note: I created a new `DateTime` instance from the UNIX timestamp, English textual representation may lead to an error.

### Other formats

I recommend you to read the [DateTime::format()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method documentation along with the [date()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function documentation to learn more about date formats.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp(1441065600);
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the timestamp to the `DateTime` constructor by prepending `@` character:

```
$d = new DateTime('@1441065600');
echo $d->format("Ymd");
```

See [Compound Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php#datetime.formats.compound).

Answer (score 0):

`date_format` is function in which first argument should be `DateTime` object, `date` function return string.

So first You need to create correct object.

`$date = new DateTime(strtotime(1441065600));`

and then format it with `date_format`

`echo date_format($date,'Ydm');`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` function in PHP

```
echo $temp = date("Y-m-d",1441065600);
```

Result:

```
2015-09-01
```

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php